# Is it possible to run a cron job in a web application?

Tags: java, tomcat, cron, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

In a java web application (servlets/spring mvc), using tomcat, is it possible to run a cron job type service?

e.g. every 15 minutes, purge the log database.

Can you do this in a way that is container independent, or it has to be run using tomcat or some other container?

**Please specify if the method is guaranteed to run at a specific time or one that runs every 15 minutes, but may be reset etc. if the application recycles (that's how it is in .net if you use timers)**

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted? +1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As documented in [Chapter 23. Scheduling and Thread Pooling](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/scheduling.html), Spring has scheduling support through integration classes for the `Timer` and the Quartz Scheduler (http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/). For simple needs, I'd recommend to go with the JDK `Timer`.

Note that Java schedulers are usually used to trigger Java *business oriented jobs*. For sysadmin tasks (like the example you gave), you should really prefer cron and traditional  admin tools (bash, etc).

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Spring, you can use the built-in Quartz or Timer hooks.  See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/scheduling.html

Answer (score 0):

It will be container-specific. You can do it in Java with [Quartz](http://www.opensymphony.com/quartz/;jsessionid=LDKHONNCOPJC) or just using Java's scheduling concurrent utils ([`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)) or as an OS-level cron job.

Every 15 minutes seems extreme. Generally I'd also advise you only to truncate/delete log files that are no longer being written to (and they're generally rolled over overnight).

Comment: cletus, the log file was just an example, but point taken.  Would the ScheduledExecutorService run at a fixed/gauranteed interval, or it depends on app recycling etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Jobs are batch oriented. Either by manual trigger or cron-style (as you seem to want).

Still I don't get your relation between webapp and cron-style job? The only webapp use-case I could think of is, that you want to have a HTTP endpoint to trigger a job (but this opposes your statement about being 'cron-style').

Generally use a dedicated framework, which solves the problem-area 'batch-jobs'. I can recommend quartz.