# How to call a class in every 30 minutes in java web application

Tags: java, spring, cron, struts, scheduled-tasks

I am using Tomcat with the Spring framework. I want to have a class called by the server every 30 minutes. Is there a good way to do this in Servlet, Spring, or Struts?

Comment: This solution is probably your best bet.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039349/is-it-possible-to-run-a-cron-job-in-a-web-application

Comment: You might want to accept some answers to your previous questions too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Background timer task in JSP/Servlet web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357033/background-timer-task-in-jsp-servlet-web-application)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

Answer (score -2):

You could create a new `Thread` on container startup that sleeps for 30 minutes and then performs your action. See [here](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2001/04/12/listeners.html) for information about context listeners.

Comment: A sleeping `Thread` is an extremely bad idea on a lifelong running Java EE container.